# Activated button in QMessageBox::question

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a possibility to set a default activated button to "No" instead of "Yes"

[image: 1]

```
QMessageBox::StandardButton reply=QMessageBox::question(this, "Warning ", "This will deleate your data, Do you want to continue ?",QMessageBox::No|QMessageBox::Yes);

if(reply == QMessageBox::Yes){     
     // Deleate Memory
}
else{    
     // don't deleate
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last parameter of [QMessageBox::question](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#question) is for default activated button. Default value is `QMessageBox::NoButton` which means there is no default button. replace it with `QMessageBox::No` which means button with "No" label on it. A little bit confusing.

```
QMessageBox::question(this, "Warning ", "This will deleate your data, Do you want to continue ?", QMessageBox::No|QMessageBox::Yes, QMessageBox::No);
```